# How to in main report Inserts data in table for subreport to fetch?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a JRXML which has one subreport in it's summary area, JRXML calls a oracle procedure, procedure return some data but also insert rows inside some other table , those rows which are inserted by procedure are getting accessed in subreport.

I am able to do this in Studio , but through java it's not working, subreport is always coming blank through java. i have set connection auto commit as true.

Any idea how it will work?.

Following is the **subreport jrxml** in main report.

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="-11" y="37" width="891" height="43" uuid="a8071066-22fc-46a7-9208-ebd217ddd22e"/>
    <subreportParameter name="NUMBER_FORMAT">
            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{NUMBER_FORMAT}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <subreportParameter name="REPORT_ID">
        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{REPORT_ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{ChargeWiseSummarySubReport}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

My **java code** is as follows.

```
con.setAutoCommit(true);
JasperReport jasperReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
JasperReport jasperSubReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(stream);
params.put("ChargeWiseSummarySubReport",jasperSubReport);
JasperPrint jasperPrint=(JasperPrint) JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,params,con);
```

Query on subreport

```
SELECT JCD.CHARGEID , JCD.CHARGEDESC, 
 SUM(JCD.LOCAL_REVENUE) BILLING,
SUM(JCD.LOCAL_COST) EXPENSE,
SUM(JCD.LOCAL_PROFIT) PROFIT,
'1'  OIND
FROM FS_RP_JCDATA JCD
 WHERE JCD.REPORT_ID =  $P{REPORT_ID}
```

Comment: You should post the small sample for reproduce: *jrxml* and *Java* code

Comment: If it works in *Studio* it **must** work with *Java* code. The Studio is a *Java* code too ))

Comment: Yes that is true , but i am unable to find what i need to do to make it work , if in subreport i use any other table (other than one used by procedure) it works. I have posted sample code too please check.

Comment: Post subreport jrxml, sql, so we can see what you mean with "other than one used by procedure" means what is the sql